# how to convert GPS time composed of Time, weeks and leap seconds to UTC Timestamp

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp, gps, gps-time

I receive this data from the GPS Integrated in my Vehicle:

```
INS_Time::INS_Time_Millisec[ms]   # example of the value: 295584830.0
INS_Time::INS_Time_Week[Week]  # example of the value: 2077.0
INS_Time::Leap_seconds[s]  # example of the value: 18.0
```

what I need is a UTC timestamp so I assume that I must combine all those different times from GPS to get a UTC timestamp but I don't know how this should be done. I would be thankful if someone can guide me through this.

```
example of the result I want to have: 1572430625230
```

I'm using python 3.7, if there is a library for this it would be very helpful otherwise I'm searching also for an Algorithm to do this

Comment: This might be helpful: https://python-forum.io/Thread-GPS-UTC-time-conversion

Comment: @YuvrajJaiswal thanks but I made a google search before asking this. what confused me is those week and leap seconds features that I received. the link you send me is for converting only those milliseconds to UTC but in my case I have weeks and leap seconds that I must also somehow combine it with the millisec and then I can convert to UTC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess :

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)#Notable_epoch_dates_in_computing , GPS epoch is 6 January 1980, `GPS counts weeks (a week is defined to start on Sunday) and 6 January is the first Sunday of 1980`

And according to http://leapsecond.com/java/gpsclock.htm , `GPS time was zero at 0h 6-Jan-1980 and since it is not perturbed by leap seconds GPS is now ahead of UTC by 18 seconds.`

So we have to define a `gps_epoch` and substract the given leap seconds in order to have utc datetime

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pytz

def gps_datetime(time_week, time_ms, leap_seconds):
    gps_epoch = datetime(1980, 1, 6, tzinfo=pytz.utc)
    # gps_time - utc_time = leap_seconds
    return gps_epoch + timedelta(weeks=time_week, milliseconds=time_ms, seconds=-leap_seconds)
```

With your example

```
>>>gps_datetime(2077, 295584830.0,18.0)
datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 30, 10, 6, 6, 830000, tzinfo=<UTC>)
>>>gps_datetime(2077, 295584830.0,18.0).timestamp()
1572429966.83
```

But I am quite far from your expected result (`1572430625230` even if it is expressed in ms)

Do not forget to `pip install pytz`

Comment: @jbernades thanks for your answer, but can you please explain the code? I mean I don't get why you used the 1,6,1980 and why you substract the leap seconds instead of adding it

Comment: @basilisk i have edited my answer with some explanations.

Comment: @jbernades thanks again, I ll try and see if it will work for me. do you think that I also need to add the offset in case my timezone is not GMT ?

Comment: @basilisk actually i forgot to express gps_epoch as a UTC time. I just updated the code above. If you just need timestamp the last edited code should work.

Comment: Just for enduring value of this answer, worth noting that the 18 seconds mentioned in the text is current as of the date of the answer, but it changes over time as leap seconds are added or subtracted. (Never subtracted one yet, but it's allowed by the standards.)